# Prolog - high-level purpose of WAM

Tags: prolog, vm-implementation

I am trying to understand the purpose of the WAM at a conceptual high level, but all the sources I have consulted so far assume that I know more than I currently do at this juncture, and they approach the issue from the bottom (details).  They start with throwing trees at me, where as right now I am concerned with seeing the whole forest.

The answers to the following questions would help me in this endeavor:

Pick any group of accomplished, professional Prolog implementers - the SISCtus people, the YAP people, the ECLiPSe people - whoever.  Now, give them the goal of implementing a professional, performant, WAM-based Prolog on an existing virtual machine - say the Erlang VM or Java VM.  To eliminate answers such as "it depends on what your other goals are," lets say that any other goals they have besides the one I just gave are the ones they had when they developed their previous implementations.

1. Would they (typically) implement a virtual machine (the WAM) inside of a VM (Erlang/JVM), meaning would you have a virtual machine running on top of, or being simulated by, another virtual machine?
2. If the answer to 1 is no, does that mean that they would try to somehow map the WAM and its associated instructions and execution straight onto the underlying Erlang/Java VM, in order to make the WAM 'disappear' so to speak and only have one VM running (Erlang/JVM)?  If so, does this imply that any WAM heaps, stacks, memory operations, register allocations, instructions, etc. would actually be Erlang/Java ones (with some tweaking or massaging)?
3. If the answer to 1 is yes, does that mean that any WAM heaps, stacks, memory ops, etc. would simply be normal arrays or linked lists in whatever language (Erlang or Java, or even Clojure running on the JVM for that matter) the developers were using?

What I'm trying to get at is this.  Is the WAM merely some abstraction or tool to help the programmer organize code, understand what is going on, map Prolog to the underlying machine, perhaps provide portability, etc. or is it seen as an (almost) necessary, or at least quite useful "end within itself" in order to implement a Prolog?

Thanks.

Comment: See [this answer and links](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4504325/772868).

Comment: Had seen that before.  I don't think it answers my question.

Comment: It shows you what actually an abstract machine is defining, by comparing all of them. So far, e.g. you have not mentioned WAM-registers which is the key innovation in WAM.

Comment: ... and WAM-registers are probably the weakest point when you try to map the WAM onto another VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm excited to see what those more knowledgeable than I are able to say in response to this interesting question, but in the unlikely event that I actually know more than you do, let me outline my understanding. We'll both benefit when the real experts show up and correct me and/or supply truer answers.

The WAM gives you a procedural description of a way of implementing Prolog. Prolog as specified does not say how exactly it must be implemented, it just talks about what behavior should be seen. So WAM is an implementation approach. I don't think any of the popular systems follow it purely, they each have their own version of it. It's more like an architectural pattern and algorithm sketch than a specification like the Java virtual machine. If it were firmer, the book *[Warren's Abstract Machine: A Tutorial Reconstruction](http://wambook.sourceforge.net/)* probably wouldn't need to exist. My (extremely sparse) understanding is that the principal trick is the employment of two stacks: one being the conventional call/return stack of every programming language since Algol, and the other being a special "trail" used for choice points and backtracking. (edit: @false has now arrived and stated that WAM registers are the principal trick, which I have never heard of before, demonstrating my ignorance.) In any case, to implement Prolog you need a correct way of handling the search. Before WAM, people mostly used ad-hoc methods. I wouldn't be surprised to learn that there are newer and/or more sophisticated tricks, but it's a sound architecture that is widely used and understood.

So the answer to your three-part question is, I think, both. There will be a VM within the VM. The VM within the VM will, of course, be implemented in the appropriate language and will therefore use that language's primitives for handling the invisible parts of the VM (the stack and the trail). Clojure might provide insight into the ways a language can share things with its own implementation language. You would be free to intermix as desired.

The answer to your final question, what you're trying to get at, is that the WAM *is* merely an abstraction for the purposes you describe and not an end to itself. There is not, for instance, such a thing as "portable WAM bytecode" the way compiled Java becomes portable JVM bytecode which might justify it absent the other benefits. If you have a novel way of implementing Prolog, by all means try it and forget all about WAM.

Comment: Basically, the preface to the book you linked, written by Warren himself, pretty much answers the questions asked.... :)

Comment: @Boris I promise to donate any rep I get on this question to Warren and Hassan. :)

Comment: I have the book he linked.  I didn't consider the preface as answering the question.  If it does, it answers it in such a way that I don't understand it.