# One recursive algorithm better than the other, why?

Tags: optimization, recursion, prolog

Here are two similar algorithms for `last/2`.  Why does `last_element0/2` perform better than `last_element1/2`?  With the extra code `last_element0/2` performs almost as well as `last/2`, but it is not as elegant as `last_element1/2`.  Also, `last_element1/2` throws a stack overflow error for lists that are too big, but `last_element0/2` doesn't, why?  Finally, `last_element1/2` has an extra choice point so a cut is necessary, not sure this is a huge concern here.

```
last_element0(X,Last) :-
    last_element0(X,_,Last).

last_element0([X|Xs],_,Last) :-
    last_element0(Xs,X,Last).
last_element0([],Last,Last).
```

---

```
last_element1([_|Xs],Last) :-
    last_element1(Xs,Last),
    !.
last_element1([Last],Last).
```

Here are the test results:

`last_element0/2`

```
1 ?- length(Cs, 1000000), maplist(=(c), Cs),time(last_element0(Cs,X)).
% 1,000,003 inferences, 0.031 CPU in 0.023 seconds (136% CPU, 32000096 Lips)
Cs = [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c|...],
X = c.
```

`last_element1/2`

```
2 ?- length(Cs, 1000000), maplist(=(c), Cs),time(last_element1(Cs,X)).
% 1,000,001 inferences, 0.250 CPU in 0.452 seconds (55% CPU, 4000004 Lips)
Cs = [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c|...],
X = c.
```

`last/2`

```
3 ?- length(Cs, 1000000), maplist(=(c), Cs),time(last(Cs,X)).
% 1,000,001 inferences, 0.031 CPU in 0.022 seconds (142% CPU, 32000032 Lips)
Cs = [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c|...],
X = c.
```

Comment: this was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734986/implementing-last-in-prolog)

Comment: Hm, didn't see your comment. You should probably delete your question. I will leave my answer for now, if you delete the question it will go with it.

Comment: @Boris: it's not a duplicate, but certainly related.

Comment: @false Well, it pops up on the side as "Linked" so good enough I guess?

Comment: @Boris: It is linked because there are links (by lefunction and you) to this and the other article. It has nothing to do with the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `last_element0/2` is *almost* the same as the [library implementation of `last/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#last/2), at least for SWI-Prolog. It is (much) faster because, due to the underlying implementation, the two clauses of `last_element0/3` (the helper predicate) are recognized as mutually exclusive, so no choice points are created, and no choice points need to be discarded.

However, look at this:

```
?- last_element0(Xs, X).
ERROR: Out of local stack

?- last_element1(Xs, X).
ERROR: Out of local stack

?- last(Xs, X).
Xs = [X] ;
Xs = [_G1570, X] ;
Xs = [_G1570, _G1573, X] ;
% ... and so on
```

The culprit: the **order of the clauses** for the helper predicate!

By the way, there are other ways of defining `last/2`:

```
last_reverse(List, Last) :- reverse(List, [Last|_]).
last_append(List, Last) :- append(_, [Last], List).
```

(Shameless self-promotion) See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964538/implementation-of-last-2-in-terms-of-append-3-or-reverse-2) and both answers for some more discussion about termination behavior, choice points, and efficiency (there are more links to follow there, too). I asked that question after answering [a question on programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/275680/the-dream-of-declarative-programming) and in the process realizing that I know nothing.